# Calculating surface volume in 3D Analyst is giving very small values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I calculated the volume of a reservoir using surface volume option in 3D Analyst but it is so much less than the actual volume and the 2D surface is also much less. Why is it so?

I don't know what the units are.  The coordinate system is WGS_1984.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include more details on your workflow? Also, I note there are two distinct questions here--please refine this question to include a single, answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

Your volume units are the units of your coordinate system.  In your case, WGS 1984, that would be degrees.  Cubic degrees are pretty nonsensical, and that's the reason the values are so small.

Try **[reprojecting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm)** your data to a **[projected coordinate system](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/about-projected-coordinate-systems.htm)** where the units are in metres, such as a **[UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)** projection.

Comment: if i go to layers-->properties-->coordinates system--->and choose UTM coordinates it will change the coordinates system ?. or i have to use any other option. by changing coordinates system by what i have above mentioned also i dont get the correct values, help me

Comment: No you need to reproject the data using the tool I linked to.